# Asp.NET page is loading very slow with treeview control

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I have treeview of level 3 on page where more than 200 nodes are being displayed with checkboxes.  This control show that how many records are available and what are selected.  User can uncheck existing selection and check more node as per the requirement.  So I have to load entire tree structure at time.
Page is taking more then 40 seconds to load.  This selected node will posted back to store in database.  There are many other postback events with respect to other action on the page.  Ondemand load of nodes doesn't work here.  I tried to simulate asynchronous load of the page by putting control in UpdatePanel with an invisible button.  which I am triggering with javascript when page load completes.  But still it takes significant amount of time to render the control.

Is there any better way to handle this?  Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Use a `Stopwatch` instance to time how long each operation takes. I also recommend using the SQL Profiler tool to see what your database operations are doing. Ideally a page should be generated in under 100ms (preferably under 50ms), so 40 seconds indicates something is really wrong.

Comment: To render the treeview asp won't take this much time. Are you calling a stored procedure or sqlQuery in each loop while iterating through treeview. Accessing DB will always create overhead. Post your code to populate the treeview

Comment: Entire tree strucure coming from a service which takes less then a second in a single request.  I am populating by looping.

Comment: There's no way to answer this without being able to see your code. Please use the [edit] link to update your question with some more details on how the TreeView is populated.  Otherwise we'll just be speculating on where the bottleneck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I set one property EnableClientScript = "false" and treeview started loading very fast.  Only problem was it was posting back when expanding or collapsing the tree.  So I placed TreeView inside update panel.  Now it is very fast.

Comment: This one line of code is worth its weight in gold!  The performance difference is amazing.

Answer (score 1):

client scripts generated by .net for treeview control is the cause of poor performance.
set EnableClientScript=false will do the trick